# Which file format takes the least space on my HDD?

Tags: csv, ascii, filesize, dataformat

my model generates massive output. At the moment, each model cycle results in a .csv file which contains two columns and 2151 rows. Each is filled with a data array of type integer.

One column used to be real, but by multiplying it with factor 1000 I could save it as integer*2 (16bits). In doing so, I reduced the amount of space for the file from 54KB down to 27KB. But since I produce millions of files of that structure, I need to further decrease the space for saving it onto my HDD.

Would it help to write the arrays into .txt? Or is there any other data type that could work for my purpose? I code in Fortran 90 if that's important.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that you will find storing and accessing millions of files on same filesystem harder than just coping with their total size.

Comment: each model cycle produces its own output. It's the way this model is built and unfortunately I cannot change that. The framework is coded in Python, e.g. the changing of parameters, visualization of the output and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to store the data in binary format.

That would only take 4 or 8 bytes per row, depending on the size of your integers (you mention 16bit, so that would take 2*2 bytes per row - no need for newline or seperator).

This would also eliminate the need to convert to and from plain text.